# How to show full path in `helm-source-locate` in `helm-mini`?

Tags: helm

When I use `helm-locate` directly, it shows a list full path of candidate files.  However, only basenames are shown in `helm-source-locate` section, when I use `helm-mini`.  How can we make `helm-source-locate` to show full path in `helm-mini` as well?  Because sometimes there are files with the same basename.

I tried to use and modify some codes in [helm-locate.el](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/master/helm-locate.el), but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution after reading the source code in details:

```
(setq helm-ff-transformer-show-only-basename nil)
```